# How the right way to update the fuse theme in angular?

Tags: angular

I'm begginer in angular, and I'm working in a project that is developed using the fuse theme for angular. My project is in version 13, but the last version is 15. How can I update then in the right way?

I've tried change the version in package.json, and run npm install again. But this don't work.

I have to replace the @fuse folder, is just it? or I have to do anything more?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: I landed here because I had the same issue, except, my version had to go from 13 to 17. I ended up copying all my code over to the new template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a fuse Config that needs to be updated too (you can get this from the fuse website). Be sure to check the Fuse change log because they have made updates which are not backwards compatible and would require you to start a new repo, and migrate your views and controllers.